# When we import a module, are we just making the namespace of the imported module accessible from the main module?

Tags: python, oop, object, module, namespaces

If this is true, then is any object in Python just a namespace? Because when we import a module, we use the same dot convention as an object `( example: module.function() & obj.method() )` to access the names in the module. I think accessing an attribute or a method of an object is just specifying the namespace for the attribute/method you'd like to access. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

No, you are also initializing the imported module by running all top-level statements in it (on first import only).

The reference you get with the module's name, gives access to the imported module namespace. This namespace is implemented with a dict, and accessing `mod.some_attribute` is the same as accessing `mod.__dict__['some_attribute']`.

> Is any object just a namespace ?

No, it is something more (it holds a namespace, *it is not* one). Every object is an instance of some class. Custom classes happen to implement a namespace in the same way modules do, using an internal `__dict__`.

Modules are referred in the Python documentation as organizational units for code. You can in fact think of classes much in the same way, as they provide you namespacing capabilities.

But there is no inheritance tree to be taken into account when searching for attributes in modules, as there is with classes/objects.

If you want a namespace object just for the namespace benefit itself, use a `dict`, or an empty `class`. There is even a `types.SimpleNamespace` class for that.

> I think accessing an attribute or a method of an object is just
> specifying the namespace for the attribute/method you'd like to
> access. Is this true ?

More or less (that is yes, except the "just" word). It uses the object name (a reference) to get to the namespace, and the attribute name as the key for the namespace underlying `__dict__` object, but implicit hooks may run code behind the scenes.